# Conflicts in files when installing libxml2

Tags: centos7

Very new in Linux/Unix so please advice me something for the problem here. I have trying to install `libxml2-devel` from RPM but I got this message

```
rpm -ivh libxml2-devel-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64.rpm 
error: Failed dependencies:
libxml2 = 2.9.1-5.el7_0.1 is needed by libxml2-devel-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64
```

So then I tried to install `libxml2` and got this:

```
# rpm -ivh libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64.rpm 
warning: libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 192a7d7d: NOKEY
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%]
file /usr/bin/xmlcatalog from install of libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
file /usr/bin/xmllint from install of libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
file /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2.9.1 from install of libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libxml2-2.9.1-5.el7.x86_64
```

Note that there is no Internet access on the machine and installation is offline that's why I using RPMs.

The system is running on CentOS 7.

Please advice me if I can do something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an older version of libxml2 installed, so you need to update it first.

```
rpm -Uvh libxml2-*
```

Comment: You should recommend "yum update libxml2-devel-2.9.1-5.el7_0.1.x86_64.rpm". This takes care of dependencies also.